# Iterating through matrix in python using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I want to generate a resultant matrix by iterating through 5 different matrices and firstly i want to take first value of all matrix and take the average of these values  and append the result as the first value of resultant matrix. Can anyone tell how to do this in python using numpy library??

Comment: Do all the matrices have the same shape? Are they in some container? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you want to avoid (potentially slow) python-based looping and let numpy do (faster) c-based looping (or no looping at all).

Most people would call the approach of removing explicit loops as (numpy-)vectorization which is usually very important if going for performance.

The following example creates 5 numpy-arrays with size `(3,3)` (the matrix-type, which also exists, is kind of deprecated, not used here and most numpy-users should use arrays as replacement for matrices) and calculate a new matrix containing all the averages with the same shape (elementwise-mean over matrix-cells; we are interpreting the 2d-arrays as a matrix).

Code:

```
import numpy as np

a, b, c, d, e = [np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(3,3)) for i in range(5)]

all = np.stack((a, b, c, d, e), axis=0)
print(all.shape)

x = np.mean(all, axis=0)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(e)

print(x)
```

Out:

```
(5, 3, 3)
[[0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [2 4 0]]
[[4 2 0]
 [3 3 4]
 [0 4 0]]
[[3 4 0]
 [2 2 1]
 [0 0 4]]
[[3 1 2]
 [4 3 4]
 [2 0 3]]
[[3 4 2]
 [3 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
[[ 2.6  2.2  0.8]
 [ 2.4  2.   1.8]
 [ 1.   1.6  1.4]]
```

If you still want to loop, you can just use a nested loop like:

```
for row in range(array.shape[0]):  
    for col in range(array.shape[1]):
        cell_value = array[row, col]
        ...
```

given an array of 2 dimensions.

Comment: that's a perfect answer!